# Twitter Stream API run in background on OpenShift

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, cron, openshift

I am looking to work with the twitter stream api in javascript and have a script that run successfully pulling from the streaming API.  My question is what would be the best way for me to set this up so it can run constantly.  Or would it be better to switch to the search API instead?  I am just trying to collect tweets based on a few keywords, but I want to collect a load of them and store them into Mongolab.  Would a Cron job be best for this?  I am going to use openshift to handle the streaming and processing.

I think I am looking for guidance on the best route so I don't have to constantly monitor and check that it is collecting tweets.

Thank you!

```
var Twit = require('twit');

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;



var T = new Twit({

consumer_key: '***',

consumer_secret: '***',

access_token: '***',

access_token_secret: '***'

});



var url = "***";

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {

var col= db.collection('test');

//  filter public stream on keywords

var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', {track: ['#food', 'drinks']

});



stream.on('tweet', function (data) {


        console.log("tweet: " + data);

        col.insert(data, function (err, result) {

            if (!err) {

                console.log("insert successful on tweet: " + data.id);

            } else {

                console.log(err);

            }

        });



});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone else might be able to provide a better answer but, I think using the cronjob add-on cart would be the way to go. You could set it up to execute jobs on your cartridge in timed intervals and thus would keep you from having to pull things manually. Here's a OpenShift blog article that can help you get started https://blog.openshift.com/getting-started-with-cron-jobs-on-openshift/.